# PyQT: Drag 'N Drop: hasFormat

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, mime-types

I'm trying to create a drag 'n drop label which accepts only PDF files.
To do that I try using the `mimeData().hasFormat`.

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasFormat(application/pdf):
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasFormat(application/pdf):
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

def dropEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasFormat(application/pdf):
        event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
        file_path = event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile()
        self.set_path(file_path)

        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

It does not seem to work though.

I tried it with `mimeData().hasImage` for an image file and it works.
Does `.hasFormat` support pdf files?

Comment: Try using [`QMimeData::formats`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#formats) to print a list of the formats that *are* available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the mimetype based on the url and verify that it corresponds to a pdf:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMimeDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel


class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if self.find_pdf(event.mimeData()):
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.find_pdf(event.mimeData()):
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        urls = self.find_pdf(event.mimeData())
        if urls:
            for url in urls:
                print(url.toLocalFile())
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def find_pdf(self, mimedata):
        urls = list()
        db = QMimeDatabase()
        for url in mimedata.urls():
            mimetype = db.mimeTypeForUrl(url)
            if mimetype.name() == "application/pdf":
                urls.append(url)
        return urls


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    label = Label()
    label.resize(640, 480)
    label.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```